# Sync Between Providers With Different Identities Using Sync Framework

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to use Sync Framework to synchronize user data between Active Directory and an application that provides a web service. I've created two FullEnumerationSimpleSyncProvider classes, one for Active Directory and one for the web service, and created a common data type and metadata columns that can be shared by both. Currently, they are both capable of maintaining their own ReplicaId and Metadata stores.

The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to match a result from one provider to another because they don't have matching Id information in their separate data stores, and most all of the fields that could be used to match one record to another are potential candidates for needing synchronized and can't be relied upon 100% for providing identity (i.e. username, email, etc).

Is there a mechanism in Sync Framework that I can use to do some sort of fuzzy matching to tell the framework how to match rows from one provider to another since I don't have a definite IdentityRule that I can create to match on both? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks,
Marc